# Maffetone formula activity level

Tags: running, jogging, heart-rate

I am very new to running but have been weight lifting a lot the last one and a half year, mostly compound exercises. I was looking into the Maffetone formula but still have a question regarding the "activity level":

"c)  If you have been training consistently (at least four times weekly) for up to two years without any of the problems in (a) and (b), keep the number (180–age) the same."

Does training here means running 4x a week or just physical exercise. In other words, do my compound exercises count? 152 max hr VS 157 max hr

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it means running (or the specific endurance activity you're training for). I've never seen it explicitly stated, but that's the impression I get from reading Maffetone and listening to interviews.

Being new to running, I would definitely consider subtracting 5 from the formula. Your body will need time to adjust to the weight bearing stress of running. Be patient, the pace may be much slower than what you feel like you can do. Progress is measured in months, not days.